# ibm bpm - Halting of the Service timed out

Tags: service, exit, ibm-bpm

When halting service in Process Admin console - using Halt service button - I get following message after a while:

Halting of the Service timed out. Most probably, the Process Server failed to halt the Service within short time period.

From what I can see, it happens only when said service has few (say in tenths)steps, when it has more (hundreds) steps, it works well.

Can somebody see cause of this and tell me what to do? Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

If we fail to halt a hung or long running (infinite loop) service within a short duration, process admin console does not allow to halt it.

This is the default behavior of how halt will work. Only way to restart the server to reinstate the BPM env.

Comment: Thanks for reply. So there is no way to force service halt? Can you please elaborate on this? It seems a bit unusual to me. Or do you know some source where can I read about this? Thanks again.

Comment: Yes there is no way to force service halt, except to kill the application server pid/ restart the machine cleanly (stopping nodeagent and starting nodeagent and app server back). There is source known to me since I got this knowledge by my experience in IBM BPM